# Set Datepicker MAX date From another Datepicker Value

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

So i have this simple date picker

```
<input asp-for="D_From" type="date" onchange="myFunction()" id="dfrom" min="1945-01-01" max="9999-12-31" class="form-control">
<input asp-for="D_To" type="date" id="dto" class="form-control">
```

this is my current script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("dfrom").value;
            document.getElementById("dto").min = x;
        }
    </script>
```

i want to set the max to the picked date in dfrom

ex : if dfrom date was 2020-01-01 i want the dto max 2020-01-31

Comment: What you have to do next is, figure out which month was chosen and then what the last day of that month is and set the max of dto accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with the following script.

```
<input asp-for="D_From" type="date" onchange="myFunction()" id="dfrom" min="1945-01-01" max="9999-12-31" class="form-control">
<input asp-for="D_To" type="date" id="dto" class="form-control">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("dfrom").value;
    document.getElementById("dto").min = x;
    var month = x.split('-')[1]; // chosen month
    var d = new Date(2008, month, 0);
    var lastDay = d.getDate(); // last day of month
    var maxDate = x.split('-')[0] + '-' + x.split('-')[1] + '-' + lastDay;
    document.getElementById("dto").max = maxDate;

  }

</script>
```

There's alot of room for improvements but I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried with date.getMonth but get nothing and get frustated along the way. Once again thankyou